# from a list of numbers to a list of lists with integers and tuples

Tags: python, list, variables, integer, tuples

from a list of numbers how can I go through the list by taking five numbers for iteration and placing the first two as variables and the last three inside a tuple? I have the list

```
['20','15','45','76','0','67','45','485','16','8']
```

I want `a = 20, b = 15, t = ('45','76','0')`
then I want `a = 67, b = 45, t = ('485','16','8')` and put them into a list.
As a result I would have

```
[['20','15',('45','76','0')],['67','45',('485','16','8')]]
```

I really don't know how iterate 5 items every time

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> l = ['20','15','45','76','0','67','45','485','16','8']
>>>
>>> for k in range(0,len(l),5):
...     print(l[k], l[k+1], l[k+2:k+5])
20 15 ['45', '76', '0']
67 45 ['485', '16', '8']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
l = ['20','15','45','76','0','67','45','485','16','8']

N = 5
[[l[i],l[i+1],tuple(l[i+2:i+5])]for i in range(0, len(l), N)]
```

output:

```
[['20', '15', ('45', '76', '0')],
 ['67', '45', ('485', '16', '8')]]
```